# How long does it take to process a green card for a H-1B holder?

Tags: usa, greencard

I am a H-1B visa holder(work visa) and my family holds H4 visa(dependent visa). So, what is the minimum and maximum period to process a green card after applying for it specifically?

Comment: It depends on which center would be processing your forms. Los Angeles as of today (28 Mar 2016), says last August while Washington DC says last May and a change of status. See [this site](https://egov.uscis.gov/cris/processingTimesDisplay.do).

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of "priority date" and is yours current?

Answer (score 7):

### Between 1 and 15 years

It depends on number of factors:

- if your employer is paying for premium processing
- if your application is subject to additional auditing
- your nationality
- green card preference class

There are 3 phases

### Labor Certification (aka PERM)

- Preparation by attorneys (including getting papers translated if necessary etc). A couple of months.
- Recruitment Period (as in your company posts offer to demonstrate that they can't find US resident for the position) — minimum of 90 days
- Processing by Department of Labor — 6-8 months
- (if unlucky) Additional DoL audit — 10-12 months

### I-140 Immigration Visa Petition

- Preparation by attorneys — couple of days / weeks
- USCIS processing queue depending on country of origin and Green Card preference class (EB-2, EB-3 etc).

  - can be checked in [Dept. of State's Visa Bulletin](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/law-and-policy/bulletin.html)
  - as of now:

    - India — 7-11 years
    - China (mainland) — 1-8 years
    - Philippines — up to 6 years
    - **all other countries — no wait**
- Processing by USCIS:

  - 4-6 months regular
  - 1-15 days premium

### I-485 Adjustment of Status

- Preparation by attorneys — couple of weeks
- USCIS decision — 4-8 months
- EAD: 90 days
- AP: 90 days  (I have no idea if EAD and AP can be filed at same time)

I-140 & I-485 [*can* be filed in parallel](https://www.uscis.gov/greencard/concurrent-filing-form-i-485)